# mysqli query doesn't work at webspace

Tags: php, mysqli

Im using mysqli on my localhost it works just fine, but when i upload it to my web server, the page just gets white and nothing else happens.Now i am here to ask for help if you can check on this only function i have in "functions.php" if i remove this function the page loads and if i add it back, the page gets white.

```
function getUserName($userID) { 
        global $mysqli; 
        $userID = $mysqli->real_escape_string($userID);
        $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID='".$userID."' LIMIT 1"); 
        if ($sql->num_rows > 0) { return $sql->fetch_assoc()['username']; }
        else { return 0; }
    }
```

And in the index.php i have the connection before this row.

Comment: Try adding a or `die("Unable to connect to db");` in your connection script to see if it was successful or failed.

Comment: You should also read your logs on your web server, I'm assuming apache to get a better idea.

Comment: With only 5 lines, it should be pretty easy to comment out some of them to get to the exact line that causes this. Maybe you'll see it yourself then, and if not, it will be even more easy for us to help you. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below line maybe the problem.

```
return $sql->fetch_assoc()['username'];
```

Function array dereferencing syntax comes with PHP 5.4, your server's php version may be below than 5.4.

Just check the log in the server and it will be clear.

Comment: This was the right answer thank you i will mark it at soon as i be able to